# How to edit the values in an Activity opened by a fragment from the same fragment after it has been opened

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-intent, onclick

I open the IndividualCouponsActivity from the fragment foodCouponsFragment within the parent CouponsActivity. I open the IndividualCouponsActivity with an Intent. After opening it, I want to edit the textViews and ImageViews of the IndividualCouponActivity. It should be noted that the IndividualCouponActivity is not a parent of the fragment.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                Coupon coupon = foodCoupons.get(position);

                Intent foodCouponsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), IndividualCouponActivity.class);
                startActivity(foodCouponsIntent);

                IndividualCouponActivity activity = new IndividualCouponActivity();

                activity.setValue(coupon.getCouponValue());

                activity.setCompany(coupon.getCompanyName());

                activity.setInfo(coupon.getDescription());

                activity.setPts(coupon.getPts());

                activity.setQr(coupon.getPicImageResourceId());

        }
    });
```

However, when I run the app, clicking on the listView makes the app shut down. This is what the log says at that time:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.
```

I suspect that this is rooting from my use of the new IndividualCouponActivity activity to access the class methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create your activity with new...

Pass the Coupon object to your activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("coupon", coupon); // or putSerializable()
intent.putExtras(bundle);
intent.setClass(context, IndividualCouponActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

In your activity in `onCreate()` you can get the passed coupon with:

```
getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("coupon"); // or putSerializable()
```

Then set the values to your views.

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

            Coupon coupon = (Coupon) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent foodCouponsIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), IndividualCouponActivity.class);

            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.put("value", coupon.getCouponValue());
            extras.put("companyName", coupon.getCompanyName());
            extras.put("description",coupon.getDescription());
            extras.put("pts", coupon.getPts());
            extras.put("picImageResourceId", coupon.picImageResourceId());

            foodCouponsIntent.putExtras(extras);


            startActivity(foodCouponsIntent);

    }
});
```

and then in your IndividualCouponActivity's onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         //get reference to views...
         textViewValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewValue);

         //do this for all views....


        //if all objects are String values, if not you know what you have to do...
        //here you get values from extras

        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
        String value = data.getStringExtra("value");
        String companyName = data.getStringExtra("companyName");
        String description = data.getStringExtra("description");
        String pts = data.getStringExtra("pts");
        String picImageResourceId = data.getStringExtra("picImageResourceId");


        //here update UI views
        //example

        textViewValue.setText(value);

        //do this for all views....
}
```

maybe there is some typo mistake, but this is the solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data between both activities using "putExtra"

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), IndividualCouponActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("COUPON_COMPANY_NAME", coupon.getCompanyName());
startActivity(intent);
```